# InstallHandler not being called

Tags: package-install

I have a dummy InstallHandler, just to test, like this:

```
global class PostInstallHandler implements InstallHandler
{
    global void onInstall( InstallContext context )
    {
        if ( true )
        {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException( JSON.serialize(context) );
        }
    }
}
```

As you can see, this is expected to fail. But I'm always getting success installing on Scratch environment and also on Production environments.

My managed package 2 has a package.xml with this configuration:

```
<Package xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
   <postInstallClass>PostInstallHandler</postInstallClass>
 ...
```

**Unsuccessful attempts:**

- Adding the InstallHandler information in the *Package Manager* UI;
- Using `public without sharing class`;
- Using `public class`;
- Using `public global class`.

What am I missing?!

Comment: Second-generation packages are usually developed in SFDX source format, without a `package.xml`. Have you [specified your install script in `sfdx-project.json`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_customize_installs.htm#!), or are you doing something unusual with Metadata API format?

Comment: This may be "by design" i.e. a decision that install handler failures should not be reported. (Though seems unlikely.) I suggest you confirm the install handler is run by replacing the exception with an operation that succeeds, so you are confident that the install handler is executed under the approach you are using to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following @David Reed comment, I was able to have a successful InstallHandler execution.

Sometimes is too complicated to follow the documentation. I was following this one
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=apex_post_install_script_specify.htm&type=5

But this one fits my need:
https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_dev2gp_customize_installs.htm

Once again, thanks @David Reed.